# How to draw graphs in React Native?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

Is there any good library for using graphs in react-native. Is there any way I can use highcharts with jsdom and WebView inside React-Native.

Thanks

Comment: https://react.parts/native?search=chart

Answer (score 1):

I am still looking for a similar answer

there are some library's out there but they are not up to date as of this date, because react-native develops too quickly to maintain. As of this moment i'm trying to implement a Webview with a template of a HTML page. in combination with a JS library. (how this is gonna work no idea) but it seems as a better idea opposed to waiting till a library is adaptable.

See:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html

for the implementation so far just use a template (html template ) with your own data implementation. to run a decent library.

don't forget to test without minified and developer function off. (to see how smooth it goes , or not).